# Firestore: Write a new document, then immediately return the new doc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to write -> read a newly added document in the firestore all in one go? I've been writing, then making a second query to read it, and while it works, I'm wondering if there is an alternate to what I have below. I've found similar questions here on SO, but a lot of them appear dated.

```
const someAsyncFunc = async () => {
  try {

      const lesson = await userLessonRef.get();
      if (lesson.exists) {
        // ? if lesson exists, return it.
        return lesson.data();
      }

      // ? if lesson does NOT exist, create it.
      await firebaseFirestore
        .collection(`users/${userID}/languages/${language}/lessons`)
        .doc(lessonID)
        .set({ greetings: 'hello' });

      // ? return the newly created lesson.
      const newLesson = await firebaseFirestore
        .collection(`users/${userID}/languages/${language}/lessons`)
        .doc(lessonID)
        .get();
      return newLesson.data();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error finding lesson collection', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used FireStore for a long time but doesn't the set promise also resolve to the new object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) (which is a combined read-then-write operation, there are no combined write/read operations.  If you need the entire contents of a document after writing it, then you will have to perform a read.